# A differentiable tensor operation approximating less than or equal to?

Tags: python, tensorflow, math, keras

I'm trying to maximize the number of predictions that are close to the true value, even if this results in crazy outliers that may otherwise skew a median (which I already have a working loss for) or mean.

So, I try this custom loss function:

```py
def lossMetricPercentGreaterThanTenPercentError(y_true, y_pred):
    """
    CURRENTLY DOESN'T WORK AS LOSS: NOT DIFFERENTIABLE

    ValueError: An operation has `None` for gradient. Please make sure that all of your ops have a gradient defined (i.e. are differentiable). Common ops without gradient: K.argmax, K.round, K.eval.

    See https://keras.io/losses/
    """
    from keras import backend as K
    import tensorflow as tf
    diff = K.abs((y_true - y_pred) / K.clip(K.abs(y_true), K.epsilon(), None))
    withinTenPct = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(K.less_equal(diff, 0.1), tf.int32), axis= -1) / tf.size(diff, out_type= tf.int32)
    return 100 * (1 - tf.cast(withinTenPct, tf.float32))
```

I understand that at least the `less_equal` function isn't differentiable (I'm not sure if it's also throwing a fit over `tf.size`); is there some tensor operation that can approximate "less than or equal to"?

I'm on Tensorflow 1.12.3 and cannot upgrade, so even if `tf.numpy_function(lambda x: np.sum(x <= 0.1) / len(x), diff, tf.float32)` would work as a wrapper I can't use `tf.numpy_function`.

Answer (score 0):

From the error message it looks like some gradient operation has not been implemented in Keras.

You could try to use Tensorflow operations to achieve the same result (Untested!):

```
 diff = tf.abs(y_true - y_pred) / tf.clip_by_value(tf.abs(y_true), 1e-12, 1e12))
 withinTenPct = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(tf.less_equal(diff, tf.constant(0.1, dtype=tf.float32, shape=tf.shape(diff)), tf.int32)))
 return 100.0 * (1.0 - tf.cast(withinTenPct, tf.float32))
```

Alternatively, you can try the `tf.keras.losses.logcosh(y_true, y_pred)`.

As it seems to fit your use case. See [Tf Doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.12/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/logcosh)